# Why is nothing displaying after hitting install URL - Shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I am developing a shopify app using [phpish/shopify_app-skeleton](https://github.com/phpish/shopify_app-skeleton)

After going through the installation guidelines when I hit the installation URL `http://path-to-new_prj/install.php?shop=example-shop.myshopify.com` (replaced shop URL and app URL respectively) I get the following URL in my address bar and nothing displays:

```
http://shopifyappURL.com/?hmac=e090ac9d76fd37aa668800a867ae91a415cec6dbc8885efa6b2a4af590da5a84&shop=kf-shop123.myshopify.com&signature=3f17cfc25b6414f9e8bf172e36138eb6&timestamp=1453815403
```

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see anything because the link you provided triggers index file. Which is empty in the skeleton you're using.

When you go to install.php you should be redirected to Shopify store to confirm permissions your app asks. Only on initial installation or updating those permissions. After hitting 'Install App' button Shopify will get you to your *callback URL*. If app has been installed already you would pass the Shopify step and immediately get to the *callback URL*.

There's a note in the shopify_app-skeleton's description:

> Use http://path-to-new_prj/oauth.php as the Callback URL

The fact that you've been redirected to index file means you have not set that callback URL in your app's settings or set it incorrectly. For instance you used root path instead of oauth.php file. Please make sure you did it correctly.